# Struggeling with Anroid Studio Kotlin ProgressBar uneven filling animation speed

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, progress-bar, android-animation, android-progressbar

I am new to coding and most of my coding and unoptimized but I come straight to the point:

When I start the activity the progressBars should fill up to the calculated fill status. They do but the progressbar for 20 Minutes and 2 hours fill up nearly instant and the longer the progressBar durantion the longer it takes to animate the fill status. I want them all to fill up to the calculated fill status over the time of 2 seconds. So if one bar is filled 100% and another is filled 30 percent the should reach 100 percent and 30% at the same time. I add my xml code in case you need it.

Thank you in advance. I am tired of chatgpt giving me repeatedly the same 3 wrong options.

```
package com.fltg.frei3

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.TextView
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
import java.util.*
import android.animation.ValueAnimator

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var timeTextView: TextView
    private lateinit var backButton: Button
    private lateinit var progressBar1: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressBar2: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressBar3: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressBar4: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressBar5: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressBar6: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressBar7: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressBar8: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressBar9: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressBar10: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressBar11: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressBar12: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressBar13: ProgressBar

    private lateinit var handler: Handler
    private lateinit var timer: Timer
    private var elapsedTimeInMilliseconds: Long = 0
    private lateinit var adView: AdView
    private lateinit var backgroundChange: BackgroundChange

    private var progress1 = 0
    private var progress2 = 0
    private var progress3 = 0
    private var progress4 = 0
    private var progress5 = 0
    private var progress6 = 0
    private var progress7 = 0
    private var progress8 = 0
    private var progress9 = 0
    private var progress10 = 0
    private var progress11 = 0
    private var progress12 = 0
    private var progress13 = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        timeTextView = findViewById(R.id.timeTextView)
        backButton = findViewById(R.id.backButton)
        progressBar1 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1)
        progressBar2 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2)
        progressBar3 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar3)
        progressBar4 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar4)
        progressBar5 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar5)
        progressBar6 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar6)
        progressBar7 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar7)
        progressBar8 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar8)
        progressBar9 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar9)
        progressBar10 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar10)
        progressBar11 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar11)
        progressBar12 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar12)
        progressBar13 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar13)

        handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        adView = findViewById(R.id.adView)

        // Initialize the timer
        timer = Timer()

        backButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (::timer.isInitialized) {
                timer.cancel() // Stop the timer when going back
            }
            finish()
        }

        val savedDateTime = intent.getStringExtra("savedDateTime") ?: ""

        if (savedDateTime.isNotEmpty()) {
            elapsedTimeInMilliseconds = DateTimeHelper.calculateElapsedTimeInMilliseconds(savedDateTime)
            startTimer()
        }

        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        adView.loadAd(adRequest)

        // Initialize the BackgroundChange class
        backgroundChange = application as BackgroundChange

        // Get the selected gradient from SharedPreferences and set the background
        val selectedGradient = backgroundChange.getSelectedGradient()
        setActivityBackground(selectedGradient)
    }

    private fun animateProgressBar(progressBar: ProgressBar, targetProgress: Int) {
        val animationDuration = 2000L // 2000 milliseconds

        val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(progressBar.progress, targetProgress)
        animator.duration = animationDuration

        // Update the progress as the animation progresses
        animator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
            val progress = animation.animatedValue as Int
            progressBar.progress = progress
        }

        animator.start()
    }



    private fun startTimer() {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                elapsedTimeInMilliseconds += 100
                updateProgressBars()

                handler.post {
                    // Additional updates when the timer is running
                }
            }
        }, 0, 10000) // Adjust the update interval as needed
    }

    private fun updateProgressBars() {
        // Set the maximum duration for each progress bar
        val maxDuration1 = 1_200_000 // 20 minutes
        val maxDuration2 = 7_200_000 // 2 hours
        val maxDuration3 = 86_400_000 // 24 hours
        val maxDuration4 = 172_800_000 // 48 hours
        val maxDuration5 = 259_200_000 // 72 hours
        val maxDuration6 = 1_209_600_000 // 2 weeks
        val maxDuration7 = 2_628_000_000 // 1 month
        val maxDuration8 = 7_884_000_000 // 3 months
        val maxDuration9 = 15_768_000_000 // 6 months
        val maxDuration10 = 31_536_000_000 // 1 year
        val maxDuration11 = 157_680_000_000 // 5 years
        val maxDuration12 = 315_360_000_000 // 10 years
        val maxDuration13 = 473_040_000_000 // 15 years

        // Calculate the progress for each progress bar
        progress1 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration1 * 100).toInt()
        progress2 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration2 * 100).toInt()
        progress3 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration3 * 100).toInt()
        progress4 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration4 * 100).toInt()
        progress5 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration5 * 100).toInt()
        progress6 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration6 * 100).toInt()
        progress7 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration7 * 100).toInt()
        progress8 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration8 * 100).toInt()
        progress9 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration9 * 100).toInt()
        progress10 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration10 * 100).toInt()
        progress11 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration11 * 100).toInt()
        progress12 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration12 * 100).toInt()
        progress13 = (elapsedTimeInMilliseconds.toFloat() / maxDuration13 * 100).toInt()

        // Update all progress bars
        runOnUiThread {
            animateProgressBar(progressBar1, progress1)
            animateProgressBar(progressBar2, progress2)
            animateProgressBar(progressBar3, progress3)
            animateProgressBar(progressBar4, progress4)
            animateProgressBar(progressBar5, progress5)
            animateProgressBar(progressBar6, progress6)
            animateProgressBar(progressBar7, progress7)
            animateProgressBar(progressBar8, progress8)
            animateProgressBar(progressBar9, progress9)
            animateProgressBar(progressBar10, progress10)
            animateProgressBar(progressBar11, progress11)
            animateProgressBar(progressBar12, progress12)
            animateProgressBar(progressBar13, progress13)
        }
    }

    private fun setActivityBackground(selectedGradient: Int) {
        val backgroundResourceId = when (selectedGradient) {
            1 -> R.drawable.backgroundgradient
            2 -> R.drawable.backgroundgradient2
            3 -> R.drawable.backgroundgradient3
            4 -> R.drawable.backgroundgradient4
            5 -> R.drawable.backgroundgradient5
            6 -> R.drawable.backgroundgradient6
            else -> R.drawable.default_background
        }

        findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundResource(backgroundResourceId)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        timer.cancel() // Stop the timer when the activity is destroyed
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headingTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Gesundheitsfortschritt"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="20 Minuten:\nHerzfrequenz wie Nichtraucher\nKörpertemperatur wie Nichtraucher"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headingTextView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2 Stunden:\nSauerstofftransport normalisiert"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="24 Stunden:\nHerzinfarktrisiko sinkt bereits"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2 Tage:\nGeruchs- und Geschmackssinn sensibler"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3 Tage:\nAtmen wird leichter\nBronchien entspannen sich"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar5"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2 Wochen:\nbessere Durchblutung\nStabilerer Kreislauf"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar6"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1 Monat:\nHustenanfälle gehen zurück\nAbgeschlagenheit geht zurück\nKurzatmigkeit geht zurück"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar7"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView7"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3 Monate:\nLugenkapazität bis zu 30 Prozent gesteigert\nBronchien reinigen sich"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar7"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar8"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView8"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="6 Monate:\nLunge allmählich gereinigt\nSchleim abgebaut\nNasennebenhöhlen Verstopfung geht zurück\nInfektionsgefahr verringert"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar8" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar9"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView9"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1 Jahr:\nRisiko koronare Herzkrankheit halbiert\nHerz-Kreislaufsystem normalisiert sich"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar9"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar10"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5 Jahre:\nHerzinfarktrisiko wie Nichtraucher\nGebärmutterhalskrebs wie Nichtraucher"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar11"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView11"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10 Jahre:\nLungenkrebsrisiko halbiert"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar11"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar12"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView12"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeTextView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="15 Jahre:\nRisiko koronare Herzkrankheit wie Nichtraucher"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar12"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar13"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFFF"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeTextView13"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar13"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7889219332409822/8002076735" />

    <!-- Der "Zurück"-Button wird außerhalb der ScrollView platziert -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Zurück"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried multiple approaches but either the progressbars with smaler maximumamount fill up slower or the progressbars with higher maximum amount fill up slower. I am lost.